Что такое ссылочные квалификаторы в С++ 11?
Изучаю С++ по этому документу:
https://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/11
Сейчас на пункте: ссылочные квалификаторы
Статья к пункту по адресу:
https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2439.htm
Т.е. заголовок по ссылке: Расширение семантики перемещения до *this
Я с семантикой перемещения знаком хорошо. Но я читал и не могу понять суть этого изменения С++11. Объясните пожалуйста простыми словами что такое ссылочные квалификаторы.

Rationale for the proposal is presented in document N1821. Открываем N1821: Proposal (informal) Allow the following two overloadable member function forms: struct X {     R f(...) cv &;   // Bind *this as an lvalue reference     R f(...) cv &&;  // Bind *this as an rvalue reference }; См. Member functions with ref-qualifier.

& после объявления функции в классе.
